# updating a post by a page using koala gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, koala

Just digging into Koala gem and using it to create feed post to a page. I can successfully create a post, but struggling to make the update work this is what I'm using to create a post

```
@page_graph.put_wall_post('post on page wall')
```

Comment: you've to use get_object first.

Comment: @dhaliman

`@page_graph.get_object("396591690742821_396764264058897", 'feed', :message => "updating test test test")`

am i missing something?